# Functional derivative of meta-generalized gradient approximation (meta-GGA)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-delta-distributions, variational-calculus, density-functional-theory, functional-derivatives

I am not able to derive Eq. 21 of this paper

> F. Zahariev, S. S. Leang, and Mark S. Gordon, "Functional derivatives of meta-generalized gradient approximation (meta-GGA) type exchange-correlation density functionals",
>   The Journal of Chemical Physics 138, 244108 (2013); https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4811270
>
> https://www.researchgate.net/publication/245026289_Functional_derivatives_of_meta-generalized_gradient_approximation_meta-GGA_type_exchange-correlation_density_functionals.

I attached herewith the steps of my derivation which I have tried.
Can you please help me to derive that equation? Looking forward to your kind reply.

$$\tau({\bf r}') = \frac{1}{2}\sum_i|\nabla\psi_i({\bf r'})|^2
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_i \int |\nabla\psi_i({\bf r'})|^2 \delta^3({\bf r}-{\bf r}')d{\bf r}',\tag{2} $$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\delta \tau({\bf r}')}{\delta \psi_i({\bf r})}&= - \nabla\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial (\nabla\psi_i({\bf r}))}\Big(\frac{1}{2}|\nabla\psi_i({\bf r'})|^2 \delta^3({\bf r} - {\bf r}')\Big)\\
 &= -\nabla \cdot (\nabla\psi_i({\bf r})\delta^3({\bf r} - {\bf r}'))\\
&= - \nabla\psi_i({\bf r})\cdot\nabla\delta^3({\bf r}-{\bf r}') - \nabla^2\psi_i({\bf r})\delta^3({\bf r}-{\bf r}').
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: DOI: http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.4811270

Comment: The site standard for maths and formula is [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and we actively discourage people from posting images.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: The published eq. (21) does not seem correct because of a factor of 2 and carelessness of whether the argument is primed or unprimed.

Hints: Use that $$\frac{\delta \psi_j({\bf r}^{\prime})}{\delta \psi_i({\bf r})}~=~\delta^i_j ~\delta^3({\bf r}^{\prime}\!-\!{\bf r}),$$

so that

$$\begin{align} \frac{\delta \tau({\bf r}^{\prime})}{\delta \psi_i({\bf r})}
~=~&\sum_j\nabla^{\prime} \psi_j({\bf r}^{\prime})\cdot \nabla^{\prime}\frac{\delta \psi_j({\bf r}^{\prime})}{\delta \psi_i({\bf r})}\cr
~=~&\nabla^{\prime} \psi_i({\bf r}^{\prime})\cdot \nabla^{\prime}\delta^3({\bf r}^{\prime}\!-\!{\bf r})\cr
~=~&-\nabla^{\prime} \psi_i({\bf r}^{\prime})\cdot \nabla\delta^3({\bf r}\!-\!{\bf r}^{\prime})\cr
~=~&\ldots\cr
~=~&-\nabla \psi_i({\bf r})\cdot \nabla\delta^3({\bf r}\!-\!{\bf r}^{\prime}) -\delta^3({\bf r}\!-\!{\bf r}^{\prime})~\nabla^2 \psi_i({\bf r})  . \end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather specialized for stackexchange (IMHO) although it's not impossible that some expert may be able to answer it definitively. I am not that person. However, I can say that your derivation seems fine to me, and that eqns (128) and (129) of [*Int J Quant Chem,* **116,** 1641 (2016)](https://doi.org/10.1002/qua.25224) by Della Sala *et al* (Open Access) are identical with your equations. And I can't see an easy way to transform your result into equation (21) of the paper you cite. So, a possible answer is that they made a slip there. But this doesn't exclude someone coming along and showing that the results are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir. The reference you have provided was very helpful in deriving the expression for the exchange-correlation potential for meta-GGA functional.